# Todays date minus a number from a integer field

Tags: sql

Im new to SQL. I have a field (ContractDays) with an integer (number of days from a datediff) and want to create a date field with a value of todays date minus the number in ContractDays field. Can you help please?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Too many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mssql. You can do this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, -ContractDays, GETDATE())
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Upvoted, but in fact the asker asked for a new column, which implies alter and update.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL contains datetime as number value. Integer part is number of days since 1/1/1753.
So you can write

```
select GetDate() - ContractDays
```

But it is better to use DATEADD

Answer (score 0):

You need to `alter` the `table` in [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3001.htm), [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) or [MS SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) to add a new `column`, let's call it `ContractDate`.

After you have this `column`, you need to `update` it to have the correct value.

Oracle:

```
update Contracts
set ContractDate = (SYSDATE - ContractDays)
```

MySQL:

```
update Contracts
set ContractDate = date_add(now(), INTERVAL -ContractDays DAY)
```

MS SQL (courtesy to Arion):

```
update Contracts
set ContractDate = DATEADD(day, -ContractDays, GETDATE())
```